# Arranging functions in order of growth rate

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics

I am very confused with this problem: arrange the following functions in ascending order of growth rates [for these functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adidn.png). I know based on Big O ranking, that $100$ is the fastest and $2^n$ is the slowest. I am uncertain on comparing functions especially these that have long exponents. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards - big $O$ describes how the function behaves over large $n$. The function $f(n) = 100$ doesn't grow at all, whereas $g(n) = 2^n$ grows quite rapidly.

For the particular problem the important part is simplifying the $\log$ expressions - here are the important rules for this:

- $a^{\log_a{x}} = x$
- $ b \log y = \log y^b$

If you apply this you can simplify some of the log expressions.

The other thing to note is that $n$ grows faster than any power of $\log n$, and $a^n$ grows faster than any polynomial in $n$.

Example:

$$ 2^{3 \log_2 n} = 2^{\log_2 n^3} = n^3$$

where I first use the second rule I mention above and then use the first rule.

Comment: Yes, trying to simplify was one of the issues. So, would I be correct in saying that for the 3rd and 6th functions they can be simplified to n?

Comment: Not quite. The 4th function can be simplified to just $n$, but the others are a little more involved. If you can edit your post with some steps I can guide you, but the 6th on should be $n^3$.

Comment: I guess I need to do more research into simplifying the log functions because that is stopping me from proceeding with the rest of the problem

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the khanacademy video series on simplifying logarithms if you haven't seen this before. In the meanwhile I've edited in an example of simplifying the 6th expression.